# Filling Out a Matrix for Excel Using Survey Data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table with two fields. The first is where somebody is, and the second is who showed up. Using this I want to create a table with the amount of occurrences of a somebody showing up over a certain time.

[image: This is an example]

But I can't seem to get it to scan only one row of data at a time using `COUNTIF` to make sure that both places are satisfied and I can seem to use `IF` statements correctly. Does anyone have an ideas on what commands would work? I've tried `COUNTIFS`, `COUNTIF`, `IF` and `AND` statements together but none seem to do this autofilling nature like I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've attempted `COUNTIFS` using [correct syntax](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842), I'm 90% sure your problem is with locking ranges and references. `COUNTIF` is exactly the function you want for this task.

Assuming the data is in locations as I've shown, this formula in B2 will copy across and down without restriction:

`=COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$10,$A2,$F$2:$F$10,B$1)`

Pay close attention to which cell reference arguments are locked (using `$`) and which are not.

[image]

Comment: Ah okay, I've gotten it to work with your formatting. But I have run into an issue I did not consider. So my survey allows for multiple boxes to be checked, which puts the results into my survey like this ["John, Jake"]. Do you know if this syntax could be modified to work there aswell or if I will have to use a different route?

Comment: This is what I've come up with, but it seems to only work when checking one cell. `=COUNTIFS(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B11,$C$3[This is where I want the range])),$B11,"No"),$B11,$D$3[This is where I want the range])),,C$6)` Do you know if there is any way for that command to work with ranges instead of single cells?

Comment: You could probably get it to work with array formulas or VBA. It would be much more efficient to refactor your import to get it to create single records in your visits table.